# Validar formulario PHP en el mismo archivo y luego enviarlo a otro archivo PHP

Tags: php, formularios, validación

Soy estudiante de DAW y tengo un trabajo sobre formularios PHP, el trabajo está casi terminado; pero, lo que necesito es validar un formulario en el mismo archivo y si pasa la validación, enviar esos datos a otro archivo PHP.

Esta es la forma como estoy haciendo la validación en el mismo archivo:

```
<form class="formulario" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">

</form>
```

Pero, no encuentro la forma de enviar los datos de este mismo formulario a otro archivo, una vez pasada la validación.

Necesito de su ayuda, he buscado por todas partes y no encuentro algo acerca de este caso.

Saludos.

Comment: "Enviarlo a otro archivo"? Que yo sepa no se puede enviar nada a un archivo. Puedes pasárselo a una función o un método de una clase, pero de cualquiera de las maneras lo que se hace es importar el código del otro archivo en donde te encuentras ahora, y ahí ya puedes usarlo (creando una clase o invocando la función directamente). Una vez estás en php, no vas a realizar una llamada http a otro de tus archivos, directamente invocas el código necesario. Te recomiendo que busques cómo importar funciones o clases.

Comment: No estoy seguro del todo pero según entiendo lo que quieres es algo así:
1 - Enviar formulario
2 - Validar datos del formulario
3 - Si la validación es ok 
3b -> Recoger los datos validados en un array
3c -> Enviar esos datos a otro archivo (redirección) por $_GET
3d -> El archivo nuevo recoge esos datos por la url con GET
4 - Si no valida repetir proceso en el mismo archivo actual.
Es solo una idea o ejemplo que se me ocurre como ejercicio.

Comment: Gracias a los dos por tomarse el tiempo de leer la pregunta y responder. Resumo un poco el enunciado de la tarea, para tratar de explicarme mejor: En datos.php, el usuario rellena el formulario, en esta misma página se hace la validación de los campos (nombre, fecha, dni, email, etc.), si no pasa la validación se llama a sí mismo, mostrando los errores y los campos correctos rellenados automáticamente; si la validación es ok, se llama a procesa.php que procesará y mostrará la información ingresada en Datos.php. Lo tengo todo listo; pero, no sé como pasar los datos a procesa.php.

Comment: Al final he decidido recoger los datos en el primer archivo PHP y enviarlos al segundo archivo para hacer la validación.

Si no pasa la validación, mostrar los errores en ese mismo archivo y he añadido un botón de "volver" hacia el primer formulario para que el usuario rellene los campos erróneos.

Si la validación es ok, desplegar el nuevo formulario con los datos ya procesados.

Es una tarea de "Desarrollo en entorno servidor", por eso no es permitido usar JS, todo el proceso debe ser con PHP.

Saludos.